# "AttributeError" using mainloop() function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I got an error that says:
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mainloop'"

I wrote my first GUI in python but I got an error using the mainloop function.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk().configure(bg="black")


def main():
    logo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Logo1.png")
    logo2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Logo2.png")
    logo3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\Logo3.png")

    # Creates labels
    lab1 = tk.Label(root, image=logo1).pack()
    lab2 = tk.Label(root, image=logo2).pack()
    lab3 = tk.Label(root, image=logo3).pack()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `root = tk.Tk().configure(bg="black")` sets `root` to the result of `.configure()` (which is None), NOT the result of `.Tk()` as you're assuming elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.configure()` method doesn't return anything (i.e. implicitly returns `None`). Try this instead:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="black")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this -

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg="black")
```

And rest remains the same. The error is because the result of `configure` is `None` and `NoneType` has no attribute called `mainloop`.